# Setting up k8s manifest image when using git commit hash for image tags

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I feel like I'm missing something basic with how to tag docker images properly and pull images with k8s.

My scenario:
I have a QA, stage, and prod environment. I'm using Jenkins to build & push my image to an Azure Container Registry (ACR). I have an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster for each environment with a deployment that pulls the image from the ACR. We're more or less using GitFlow as our branching strategy. When a feature branch is merged into develop, we want to build & tag a new QA image. When going to stage, we cut a release branch, then we would then manually kick off a Jenkins build/tag/push of stage image from the release branch. Then once stage testing is done, we'd want to re-tag the stage image as prod and push.

I've done a good bit of reading, and it seems that most people recommend using the git commit hash as the tag so that the image tag is unique and its easy to know what is running in your environments. The alternative would be to just use qa, stage, prod tags and push new images with the same tag. This alternative seems to be frowned upon.

My question:
How do I use unique tags (git commit hash or otherwise) and still be able to pull the image with the correct tag in my k8s manifest. Without using a static tag for each environment, how does my deployment know what tag to look for when pulling an image?

Frowned upon, but how do I make tags unique?:

```
    containers:
        - name: container-name
          image: repository/imagename:qa
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Comment: You can use a tool like Helm or Kustomize to replace the tag value at deployment time.

Comment: @DavidMaze was trying to avoid Helm because I didn't think my situation was complex enough for it, but maybe it is